# How to set SSRS parameters text multi language

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, multilingual

I want to set my SSRS reports to be multi language. I know to configure labels to be multi language, but I didn't find yet how to set the parameters multi language.

It is possible to aproach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 7 year old thread, but cannot seem to find anything more recent. It wasn't a supported feature for SSRS 2008, but they hoped to add this to later versions. This thread does offer some other solutions, but I guess not exactly what you were hoping for.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2ccabb76-9d08-48be-80fb-eefa1104ddf8/change-parameter-prompt-name-based-on-language-used?forum=sqlreportingservices